# how to add base link or world frame rviz

Tags: ros, iai-kinect2, 3d-object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I m new user of rviz
I am using Kinect 2 and want to see point cloud information
I want to see the cloud information in rviz however my fixed frame popup only shows map ... however in different tutorial i have observed many other frames availble in the pop up. How can i add these frames in my pop up menu and how these are useful. and for me which frame is important.

Plz reply with details keeping in mind that i m new user of ros and rviz thankss

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234626/how-to-add-base-link-or-world-frame-rviz/) by [noman](https://answers.ros.org/users/26704/noman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-05-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-05-18**:
AFAIK, It takes automatically if the frame exists?

**Comment by [noman](https://answers.ros.org/users/26704/noman/) on 2016-05-19**:
what is AFAIK sorry as i told you that i m totaly new user

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-05-19**:
It means: As far as I know :)

**Comment by [noman](https://answers.ros.org/users/26704/noman/) on 2016-05-20**:
haha ok got it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Orhangazi44 is right.
`rviz` displays all frames that are present in the tf tree (i.e. broadcasted to tf using a tf broadcaster), and, by default, just `map`.

If there are no other frames broadcasted, it will not show any. So you need to add respective tf broadcasters.

If you, however, just want to visualize the point cloud data in the frame it is sent in, it typically is enough to manually type the `frame_id` in which the data is published (check the `header/frame_id` field with `rostopic echo`) in the `fixed_frame` field in `rviz`.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noman](https://answers.ros.org/users/26704/noman/) on 2016-05-20**:
i didnt get this bro .. please elaborate. how a frame or world frame can be added ...